# I'm trying to make a sumifs column in Power BI language M

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, sumifs, m

What I try to do is to make a `sumifs` column.

I have three columns, the first has an ID, the second has the date and the third one the cost.

How can I sum the costs of all the columns for each line that coincides the ID and has a date from the date of the line and 6 months before?

Thanks

I have tried to use IAs but PowerBI said that it's a bucle

Comment: Needs a data sample as text and an example of the expected output from that data. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```ml
let
  Source = #table(
    type table [ID = Int64.Type, Date = date, Cost = Currency.Type],
    {
      {1, #date(2024,1,31), 33.22},
      {2, #date(2024,2,10), 12.34},
      {1, #date(2024,4,15), 100},
      {1, #date(2024,9,15), 1000}
    }
  ),
  #"Added Sum" = Table.AddColumn(
    Source,
    "Sum",
    each
      let
        ID = [ID],
        Date = [Date],
        MinDate = Date.AddMonths(Date, -6),
        Filtered = Table.SelectRows(
          Source,
          each [ID] = ID and [Date] > MinDate and [Date] <= Date
        ),
        Sum = List.Sum(Filtered[Cost])
      in
        Sum,
    Currency.Type
  )
in
  #"Added Sum
```

Returns

| ID | Date | Cost | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/31/2024 | 33.22 | 33.22 |
| 2 | 2/10/2024 | 12.34 | 12.34 |
| 1 | 4/15/2024 | 100.00 | 133.22 |
| 1 | 9/15/2024 | 1,000.00 | 1,100.00 |